# SVG animation(morphing) onClick

Tags: animation, svg

I have followed the tutorial from this page:
http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/path_morphing.shtml

The two shapes just blink between each other. Does anyone know why they dont animate / morph to each other?

for some reason my fiddle is not doing anything but the svg code is the same as what I have on my desktop where they blink between each other, not morph... I basically downloaded the html / svg files from the tutorial above and posted in my svg code

http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/

```
<path  stroke="deepskyblue" stroke-width="15" d="M20.553,16.551c-0.955,0-1.84,0.313-2.559,0.826c-0.083-0.045-8.388-4.366-8.388-4.366S17.76,8.759,17.9,8.694
c0.742,0.559,1.654,0.903,2.653,0.903c2.445,0,4.426-1.983,4.426-4.425c0-2.443-1.981-4.423-4.426-4.423
c-2.443,0-4.422,1.979-4.422,4.423c0,0.054,0.023,0.148,0.015,0.158C16.137,5.339,7.891,9.625,7.829,9.66
C7.073,9.104,6.176,8.756,5.176,8.756c-2.445,0-4.426,1.98-4.426,4.423c0,2.446,1.981,4.426,4.426,4.426
c1.117,0,2.104-0.422,2.905-1.111c0.255,0.147,8.022,4.17,8.077,4.205c-0.002,0.033-0.027,0.183-0.027,0.278
c0,2.441,1.979,4.423,4.422,4.423c2.445,0,4.426-1.981,4.426-4.423C24.979,18.53,22.998,16.551,20.553,16.551z">
<animate dur="&animDuration;" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" values="M20.553,16.551c-0.955,0-1.84,0.313-2.559,0.826c-0.083-0.045-8.388-4.366-8.388-4.366S17.76,8.759,17.9,8.694
c0.742,0.559,1.654,0.903,2.653,0.903c2.445,0,4.426-1.983,4.426-4.425c0-2.443-1.981-4.423-4.426-4.423
c-2.443,0-4.422,1.979-4.422,4.423c0,0.054,0.023,0.148,0.015,0.158C16.137,5.339,7.891,9.625,7.829,9.66
C7.073,9.104,6.176,8.756,5.176,8.756c-2.445,0-4.426,1.98-4.426,4.423c0,2.446,1.981,4.426,4.426,4.426
c1.117,0,2.104-0.422,2.905-1.111c0.255,0.147,8.022,4.17,8.077,4.205c-0.002,0.033-0.027,0.183-0.027,0.278
c0,2.441,1.979,4.423,4.422,4.423c2.445,0,4.426-1.981,4.426-4.423C24.979,18.53,22.998,16.551,20.553,16.551z; M17.491,19.042c-0.382,0-0.765-0.146-1.057-0.438s-6.915-6.936-6.937-6.936
c-0.022,0-6.354,6.354-6.937,6.936c-0.581,0.582-1.529,0.584-2.113,0c-0.584-0.583-0.576-1.537,0-2.114
c0.576-0.576,6.936-6.909,6.936-6.936c0-0.028-6.356-6.356-6.936-6.936s-0.584-1.53,0-2.114c0.584-0.583,1.536-0.578,2.113,0
C3.14,1.082,9.259,7.201,9.306,7.248C9.352,7.294,9.482,7.44,9.498,7.44c0.015,0,6.356-6.356,6.937-6.937s1.53-0.584,2.114,0
c0.583,0.583,0.587,1.526,0,2.113c-0.588,0.588-6.937,6.916-6.937,6.937c0,0.021,6.358,6.358,6.937,6.936
c0.577,0.578,0.583,1.53,0,2.114C18.256,18.896,17.874,19.042,17.491,19.042z"/>
```

there should be the same amount of points on both svg, 18points each and all points are the same I went through both illustrator files and made them all curvy.

Also, would someone know how to do this animation onClick once..then back again on next onClick rather than looping the animation on the load of the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I realize you're trying to morph your own path. The problem lies in your code here:

```
<animate dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" values="M20.553,16.551c-0.955,0-1.84,0.313-2.559,0.826c-0.083-0.045-8.388-4.366-8.388-4.366S17.76,8.759,17.9,8.694
c0.742,0.559,1.654,0.903,2.653,0.903c2.445,0,4.426-1.983,4.426-4.425c0-2.443-1.981-4.423-4.426-4.423
c-2.443,0-4.422,1.979-4.422,4.423c0,0.054,0.023,0.148,0.015,0.158C16.137,5.339,7.891,9.625,7.829,9.66
C7.073,9.104,6.176,8.756,5.176,8.756c-2.445,0-4.426,1.98-4.426,4.423c0,2.446,1.981,4.426,4.426,4.426
c1.117,0,2.104-0.422,2.905-1.111c0.255,0.147,8.022,4.17,8.077,4.205c-0.002,0.033-0.027,0.183-0.027,0.278
c0,2.441,1.979,4.423,4.422,4.423c2.445,0,4.426-1.981,4.426-4.423C24.979,18.53,22.998,16.551,20.553,16.551z; M17.491,19.042c-0.382,0-0.765-0.146-1.057-0.438s-6.915-6.936-6.937-6.936
c-0.022,0-6.354,6.354-6.937,6.936c-0.581,0.582-1.529,0.584-2.113,0c-0.584-0.583-0.576-1.537,0-2.114
c0.576-0.576,6.936-6.909,6.936-6.936c0-0.028-6.356-6.356-6.936-6.936s-0.584-1.53,0-2.114c0.584-0.583,1.536-0.578,2.113,0
C3.14,1.082,9.259,7.201,9.306,7.248C9.352,7.294,9.482,7.44,9.498,7.44c0.015,0,6.356-6.356,6.937-6.937s1.53-0.584,2.114,0
c0.583,0.583,0.587,1.526,0,2.113c-0.588,0.588-6.937,6.916-6.937,6.937c0,0.021,6.358,6.358,6.937,6.936
c0.577,0.578,0.583,1.53,0,2.114C18.256,18.896,17.874,19.042,17.491,19.042z"/>
```

This is because if you [replace it with the original](http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/1/) it works fine

```
<animate dur="30s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" values="M-2203 2143l28 -91 14 -41 0 -35 -7 -21 -7 -28 0 -27 56 -21 69 -28 28 35 83 27 139 174 132 -97 7 -104 56 -21 49 -7 48 35 77 7 83 111 209 -42 90 -90 139 -70 215 -28 21 -48 14 -42 160 -7 41 56 28 -7 111 -21 56 104 76 35 42 -63 21 -153 -83 -6 34 -105 -111 -132 -49 -62 0 -70 49 -83 35 -14 35 -21 34 -21 35 -21 21 -13 28 -7 21 -7 20 -14 14 -7 7 -14 14 -21 14 -28 7 -27 7 -56 0 -56 90 21 84 35 34 -125 14 -125 125 97 14 63 139 41 63 -83 139 35 14 -28 69 -167 77 7 55 -194 493 76 77 56 194 13 63 -90 111 14 28 28 132 21 -14 90 -7 42 0 48 -7 49 7 42 7 48 21 42 7 21 14 14 27 41 56 91 21 62 35 104 -42 49 56 97 -49 49 -118 14 -28 -14 -56 -28 -111 63 21 34 63 21 55 35 -21 76 -76 63 35 354 -112 42 -90 139 -62 28 27 125 -145 -21 -98 56 -55 55 -49 0 -35 0 -27 -7 -56 0 -56 0 -62 0 -28 35 -76 42 -160 159 -507 -48 -598 -77 -167 -27 -111 -70 -104 -160 7 -118 -257 139 -98 -28 -76 35 -104 -7 -111 84 -28 76 -97 56 -77 -14 -7 -63 -132 -14 -41 -83 -21 0 -111 90 -35 28 -132 -28 -42 -28 28 -69 -160 -35 14 -111 -70 -90z; M-1358 1980l69 -28 35 -111 -28 -90 45 -83 45 -84 71 -42 68 -41 7 -160 42 -14 21 -7 21 -14 21 -21 13 -20 42 -56 49 -49 48 -48 28 -21 28 -21 49 -76 -77 -56 28 -56 111 -55 42 83 104 7 104 -125 7 14 7 7 90 7 49 0 42 0 14 0 14 -7 20 -14 28 -14 21 -7 35 -7 35 0 41 0 42 0 28 0 28 7 20 0 28 0 7 0 7 -7 7 -14 -21 -27 -62 -42 41 -42 84 -42 111 84 49 14 103 15 84 13 83 20 146 70 0 28 7 27 7 21 0 35 -14 42 -27 90 -14 42 -7 41 -7 49 0 49 83 21 160 34 -28 70 42 28 132 27 35 -27 111 -91 21 0 41 84 -48 139 48 55 -27 84 -42 13 -42 -7 -35 -62 -69 35 -35 104 42 42 14 76 28 35 -7 41 -28 21 -28 -14 -56 -104 -77 16 -55 12 -62 49 -90 -14 -42 -153 -83 0 -23 117 -19 98 -118 125 -14 111 42 70 -28 49 -63 0 -28 -77 -41 -28 0 -118 -49 -14 -55 -14 -21 -7 -91 -90 -21 -160 -62 -7 -42 84 -83 48 14 84 -14 55 -85 78 -96 89 -93 -16 -67 -12 -102 39 -99 38 -132 -21 0 -77 -56 -55 -14 -56 -62 -55 35 -70 -49 -83 14 -56 7 -27 -77 -21 -76 0 -72 18 -67 16 -56 77 14 28 28 69 -104 77 -90 -21 -7 -63z;  M-1358 1980l69 -28 35 -111 -28 -90 45 -83 45 -84 71 -42 68 -41 7 -160 42 -14 21 -7 21 -14 21 -21 13 -20 42 -56 49 -49 48 -48 28 -21 28 -21 49 -76 -77 -56 28 -56 111 -55 42 83 104 7 104 -125 7 14 7 7 90 7 49 0 42 0 14 0 14 -7 20 -14 28 -14 21 -7 35 -7 35 0 41 0 42 0 28 0 28 7 20 0 28 0 7 0 7 -7 7 -14 -21 -27 -62 -42 41 -42 84 -42 111 84 49 14 103 15 84 13 83 20 146 70 0 28 7 27 7 21 0 35 -14 42 -27 90 -14 42 -7 41 -7 49 0 49 83 21 160 34 -28 70 42 28 132 27 35 -27 111 -91 21 0 41 84 -48 139 48 55 -27 84 -42 13 -42 -7 -35 -62 -69 35 -35 104 42 42 14 76 28 35 -7 41 -28 21 -28 -14 -56 -104 -77 16 -55 12 -62 49 -90 -14 -42 -153 -83 0 -23 117 -19 98 -118 125 -14 111 42 70 -28 49 -63 0 -28 -77 -41 -28 0 -118 -49 -14 -55 -14 -21 -7 -91 -90 -21 -160 -62 -7 -42 84 -83 48 14 84 -14 55 -85 78 -96 89 -93 -16 -67 -12 -102 39 -99 38 -132 -21 0 -77 -56 -55 -14 -56 -62 -55 35 -70 -49 -83 14 -56 7 -27 -77 -21 -76 0 -72 18 -67 16 -56 77 14 28 28 69 -104 77 -90 -21 -7 -63z; M-2203 2143l28 -91 14 -41 0 -35 -7 -21 -7 -28 0 -27 56 -21 69 -28 28 35 83 27 139 174 132 -97 7 -104 56 -21 49 -7 48 35 77 7 83 111 209 -42 90 -90 139 -70 215 -28 21 -48 14 -42 160 -7 41 56 28 -7 111 -21 56 104 76 35 42 -63 21 -153 -83 -6 34 -105 -111 -132 -49 -62 0 -70 49 -83 35 -14 35 -21 34 -21 35 -21 21 -13 28 -7 21 -7 20 -14 14 -7 7 -14 14 -21 14 -28 7 -27 7 -56 0 -56 90 21 84 35 34 -125 14 -125 125 97 14 63 139 41 63 -83 139 35 14 -28 69 -167 77 7 55 -194 493 76 77 56 194 13 63 -90 111 14 28 28 132 21 -14 90 -7 42 0 48 -7 49 7 42 7 48 21 42 7 21 14 14 27 41 56 91 21 62 35 104 -42 49 56 97 -49 49 -118 14 -28 -14 -56 -28 -111 63 21 34 63 21 55 35 -21 76 -76 63 35 354 -112 42 -90 139 -62 28 27 125 -145 -21 -98 56 -55 55 -49 0 -35 0 -27 -7 -56 0 -56 0 -62 0 -28 35 -76 42 -160 159 -507 -48 -598 -77 -167 -27 -111 -70 -104 -160 7 -118 -257 139 -98 -28 -76 35 -104 -7 -111 84 -28 76 -97 56 -77 -14 -7 -63 -132 -14 -41 -83 -21 0 -111 90 -35 28 -132 -28 -42 -28 28 -69 -160 -35 14 -111 -70 -90z; M-2203 2143l28 -91 14 -41 0 -35 -7 -21 -7 -28 0 -27 56 -21 69 -28 28 35 83 27 139 174 132 -97 7 -104 56 -21 49 -7 48 35 77 7 83 111 209 -42 90 -90 139 -70 215 -28 21 -48 14 -42 160 -7 41 56 28 -7 111 -21 56 104 76 35 42 -63 21 -153 -83 -6 34 -105 -111 -132 -49 -62 0 -70 49 -83 35 -14 35 -21 34 -21 35 -21 21 -13 28 -7 21 -7 20 -14 14 -7 7 -14 14 -21 14 -28 7 -27 7 -56 0 -56 90 21 84 35 34 -125 14 -125 125 97 14 63 139 41 63 -83 139 35 14 -28 69 -167 77 7 55 -194 493 76 77 56 194 13 63 -90 111 14 28 28 132 21 -14 90 -7 42 0 48 -7 49 7 42 7 48 21 42 7 21 14 14 27 41 56 91 21 62 35 104 -42 49 56 97 -49 49 -118 14 -28 -14 -56 -28 -111 63 21 34 63 21 55 35 -21 76 -76 63 35 354 -112 42 -90 139 -62 28 27 125 -145 -21 -98 56 -55 55 -49 0 -35 0 -27 -7 -56 0 -56 0 -62 0 -28 35 -76 42 -160 159 -507 -48 -598 -77 -167 -27 -111 -70 -104 -160 7 -118 -257 139 -98 -28 -76 35 -104 -7 -111 84 -28 76 -97 56 -77 -14 -7 -63 -132 -14 -41 -83 -21 0 -111 90 -35 28 -132 -28 -42 -28 28 -69 -160 -35 14 -111 -70 -90z"/>
```

The problem is that your paths do not **exactly** match up. You can see this in how it jumps from one shape to the next [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/3/)

Comment: hmm very interesting! Thanks! Do you know why, when I stick my svg into that it only flashes instead of animates? http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/1/

Comment: @mike Make sure to click "Update" in jsFiddle and give me the new link - you linked my same jsFiddle (:

Comment: o wow I really must be out of it today srry bout that. http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/2/

not sure how to get the svg bigger but if I do this on my own site im sure I can get the size better by adding enable-background / viewBox / height / width to the svg tag. I got this to work on a really stupid simple shape so maybe I need to remake the shapes with all rounded corners so all points are the same type...

Comment: @mike I realize now what you're trying to do. Your animate path seems to be wrong. Mind showing me what you're trying to make and describing how you created the path?

Comment: im basically just trying to get these two shapes to morph in and out of each other... Thats the question on hand... in the end I actually really need it to morph from the "share" icon to the "X" icon onClick... then back again on next click if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/4qfdD/1/ I created the paths in illustrator and made sure they both have 18 points. Inside the animation path I just added the first icon path followed by a ; then the next path.

Comment: @mike I extended my answer some. Try double checking your points to make sure your paths have **exactly** the same structure. Also, update your question with a bettered description so it's not downvoted any more

Comment: I see... So do I need to make sure the position of any of the elements are near each other, or is that irrelevant? The most important thing is the same number of points and each point needs to be the same as the other path right? So for instance if I make both icons sharp corners bezier, so both icons have all bezier points, it should work?

Comment: ok thanks I appreciate the help! I'll update my answer and double check the paths

Comment: @mike Position of the elements should not be too relevant, the important thing is that the number should be the same and (I'm unsure with this next part) that you use the same type of path

Comment: ya your right... I tried smoothing all the hard corners and it still didnt work but when I made them from scratch with really super smooth edges it worked... I think I just need to go through the original path icons and make sure all types are exactly the same. http://jsfiddle.net/c5krG/5/ Thanks I really appreciate you helping me through this!!

Comment: @mike Not a problem at all (: Glad I could help